# I want to ingest the csv data to the HDFS with Hortonworks Data Platform Sandbox

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

I'd like to store my web scraper result in HDFS in Hortonworks Data Platform Sandbox. It should automatically upload in HDFS, and then from other references, it recommended using NiFi but there's no Apache NiFi in HDP. I learning the mechanism of Kafka too, but i don't know how to send the csv files to Kafka Topics because it still in Ubuntu local, not in HDP yet.

I expecting that i can using scheduler that the program Will scrape every day, like with Oozie, so it'll be automatically scraping and also store to HDFS through Kafka in Hortonworks Data Platform environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hortonworks Sandbox has been abandoned as a project. Nifi was added to HDF, not HDP.

You can run Nifi and Kafka and HDFS all locally, or in Docker.

Nifi can read files in local filesystem, and on a schedule. You don't even need Hadoop, or Oozie.

Kafka is not intended for file transfers, however, and CSV is not a recommended format for it either, so you may want to use Nifi to parse the data into JSON or Avro before sending elsewhere

---

You could also use cron + Python Beautifulsoup + kafka-python, and don't need Nifi at all

Not clear what you plan on doing with the data, but Elasticsearch+Kibana is more useful for analysis than HDFS

Comment: I just want to doing an automatically ingest and store for the raw data with CSV and also image and video format, or maybe with the scheduler to scrape the data automatically too. Anyway thanks for the help, i'll try to put attention with the HDF for now. Thank you again.

Comment: HDF is also deprecated, or at least is no longer available for free... Hortonworks no longer exists as a company. And you're required to use HDFS? S3 + Lambda is more common for that... What is actually creating the CSV files? Why can't that be a different data format? Or, why not write the same columnar data to a database instead?

Comment: I want to doing data ingestion, and integrate it without doing analytic things. CSV is the format of the web scraper result, so maybe i'll need Oozie for the scheduler to scraping and move the result to the HDFS. I don't know for the format, maybe it can be export to the JOSN format too. I use Hortonworks Data Platform for the open-source hadoop distribution, and is there any other way for using another open-source hadoop distribution too? Cause there's no NiFi on HDP, i want to find out if HDP can be used in conjunction with HDF or no too.

Comment: Hortonworks no longer exists as a company, therefore its tools are no longer supported, as answered. Hadoop itself does not require any company-specific tooling, so you should follow http://hadoop.apache.org if you need installation setup... **However**, I would recommend you look at using Airflow (with Python + BeautifulSoup) or NiFi. Neither of these "require Hadoop", and will be much faster to setup, and far less to manage. Similarly, you should use an actual database or search-engine for analytics... For example, Clickhouse, Couchbase, Druid and Pinot have native Kafka ingestion features.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, now im using Airflow for schedule my web scraper. Now i'm facing an error with the export on airflow, maybe you can help me in my newest question^^. Thanks again.